# How to align Component in SingleScrollView in flutter?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, components, frontend

I'm creating a function that allows chips to scroll horizontally over horizontal space.
To implement this function, `Row` component was developed in `SingleScrollView`. However, as a result, it is centered. I want to make the chips pile up from the left. I have no idea what caused it.
Can someone help me with this?

[image: Unintended behavior]

My Code is here!

```dart
SliverAppBar(
  expandedHeight: 160,
  pinned: true,
  floating: false,
  brightness: Brightness.light,
  flexibleSpace: _buildFlexibleSpaceBar(model),
  bottom: PreferredSize(
    preferredSize: Size(double.infinity, 24),
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: rowChips(model.categoryList, user.id, model),
    )
  ),
),

rowChips(List chipList, String uid, MyTilViewModel model){
  return Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
    children: <Widget>[
      chipForRow('All', uid, model),
      for(var item in chipList) chipForRow(item, uid, model)
    ],
  );
}
```

```dart
Widget chipForRow(String label, String uid, MyTilViewModel model){
  return Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
    child: ActionChip(
      label: Text(label),
      shadowColor: Colors.grey[60],
      onPressed: (){
        model.getFeeds(uid, label);
        print(label);
      },
    ),
  );
}
```